# NSMutableArray : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I'm trying to store an array int[9][9] with a NSMutableArray of NSMutableArray where I store my 81 integers from the array :

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // initialization matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

        // Creating NSMutableArray instance
    TGrid = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

    [self saveGrid];
}

- (void)saveGrid {
    NSNumber *aInt;
    NSMutableArray *Grid = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:81];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            aInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:matrix[i][j]];
            [Grid addObject:aInt];
        }
    }
    [TGrid addObject:Grid];
}

- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender {
    [TGrid removeLastObject];
    NSMutableArray *Grid = [TGrid lastObject];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            matrix[8-i][8-j] = [[Grid lastObject] intValue];
            [Grid removeLastObject];
        }
    }
}
```

When saveGrid is first called by the awakeFromNib method, it works. But when I change my matrix, it calls again saveGrid, and this time I get this error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[CALayerArray addObject:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x4b36ce0'

I need your help !
Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to retain TGrid ! Otherwise, it will be deallocate by the autorelease  pool and probably a CALayer takes its place in the memory !

Best option being to create a property with retain attribute out of it and access `self.TGrid`
Don't forget to release it at the end (`dealloc`)

**edit**
It is deallocated because every instance creator class method provides Autoreleased instance (that's a rule that everyone should follow and that Apple does follow in the whole SDK).

Comment: @Bertrand use this for retaining TGrid = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10] retain];

Comment: Perhaps `TGrid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10]` is a more conventional way to create the instance.

Comment: @Bertrand, arrayWithCapacity gives an autorelease object.

Comment: need your help again :) (see my answer)

Comment: In finally find how to solve : As the used Grid (NSMutableArray) is release, I remove the lastobject (that must be nil ?) and store a new object with the same matrix stored in it.
  [TGrid removeLastObject];
  [self saveGrid];
Can you please tell me how to accept the answer ?

Comment: There is a Grey check mark on the left. Click it to make it green :-).
Cheers

Comment: @Bertrand : Delete your answer which is a question to make it respectful in regards to StackOverflow policies.

Comment: `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` will work fine, too.  `initWithCapcity:` with a bogus amount isn't helpful.